# How to call phone number field [Attribute] to register form, Which is present in checkout form?

Tags: magento2, checkout, registration

I am new to **Magento 2**. I want to know how could I display text **field[phone number] in create account page**. Which is **already present in checkout page**.

Comment: phone number field add only on register and checkout?

Comment: No I have Phone number field in checkout form. How could I call same attribute to the register form.

Comment: My register form has .First name, last name, email, password, conform password. fields.   In My checkout form has  First name, last name, email, password, PHONE NUMBER, address. fields. But I want to display same Phone number field in Register form.

Comment: @hema try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/273692/52244, hope you will get your expected output.