# How to add phone field in registration form in magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, registration

I need to add Phone field in registration form `frontend`. It is only added in `Contact Information` after registration.
Any help?

```
     <?php $block->setShowAddressFields(true); ?>
        <?php if ($block->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
            <fieldset class="fieldset address">
                <!--legend class="legend"><span><?php echo __('Address Information') ?></span></legend><br-->
                <input type="hidden" name="create_address" value="1"/>
                <!--div class="field company">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Company') ?>" type="text" name="company" id="company" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCompany()) ?>" title="<?php echo __('Company') ?>"
                               class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('company') ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div-->
                <div class="field telephone">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Phone number') ?>" type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo __('Phone Number') ?>"
                               class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="street[]" value="USA"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="city" value="USA"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="postcode" value="0000"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="country_id" value="US"/>
                <!--div class="field street required">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Address') ?>" type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getStreet(0)) ?>"
                               title="<?php echo __('Street Address') ?>" id="street_1"
                               class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                        <div class="nested">
                            <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
                            <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                                <div class="field additional">
                                    <label class="label" for="street_<?php echo $_i ?>"><span><?php echo __('Address') ?></span></label>
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getStreetLine($_i - 1)) ?>"
                                               title="<?php echo __('Street Address %1', $_i) ?>" id="street_<?php echo $_i ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php endfor; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div-->
                <!--div class="field required">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo __('City') ?>" type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>" id="city"
                               title="<?php echo __('City') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>"/>
                    </div>
                </div-->
                <!--div class="field region required">
                    <div class="control">
                        <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php echo __('State/Province') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                            <option value=""><?php echo __('Please select a region, state or province.') ?></option>
                        </select>
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo __('State/Province') ?>" type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getRegion()) ?>" title="<?php echo __('State/Province') ?>"
                               class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;" />
                    </div>
                </div-->
                <!--div class="field zip required">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?php echo __('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" id="zip"
                               class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>">
                    </div>
                </div-->
                <!--div class="field country required">
                    <div class="control"><?php echo $block->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?></div>
                </div-->

                <?php $addressAttributes = $block->getChildBlock('customer_form_address_user_attributes'); ?>
                <?php if ($addressAttributes): ?>
                    <?php $addressAttributes->setEntityType('customer_address'); ?>
                    <?php $addressAttributes->setFieldIdFormat('address:%1$s')->setFieldNameFormat('address[%1$s]'); ?>
                    <?php $block->restoreSessionData($addressAttributes->getMetadataForm(), 'address'); ?>
                    <?php echo $addressAttributes->setShowContainer(false)->toHtml() ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1">
            </fieldset>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Have you try anything.

Answer (score 1):

**Add a Phone Number (Telephone) Field in a Customer Register Page**

**before that**, We need to know that **`telephone number is a part of customer address`** section.

If we want this (Telephone) field we need to *`enable address section in Customer Register Page`*.

But `don't want to enable Address` section on registration time and **`want telephone number in Register page then we have to create custom Phone Number (Telephone) field`**.

So How to added custom field in Customer Register Page, please follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/272438/52244)

More help please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

> Override **edit.phtml** file using `customer_account_edit.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <!-- Set Custom Template for Register form -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer_edit">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Customer::form/edit.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <!-- End -->
    </body>
</page>
```

Override **form/edit.phtml** and Add Your Custom Field

Comment: You miss understand me. The field is already there, and you can fill it from `Contact Information` in `my account` after registration. I just want to show that field in registration form to be filled.

Comment: Check updated my answer

Comment: Sorry, I'm new with magento2. I may need more explanation.
in my `theme\Magento_Customer\layout\customer_account.xml` file, I added your answer code, but it showed error because both `<vendor> <Module>` tags not closed.
I copied `edit.phtml` in my `theme`, but no idea how to add my Phone no. field

Comment: It is how to enable Phone field in Magento Customer Registration Form :)

Comment: vendor module is your custom module name

Comment: but I didn't create a module

Comment: iwhich location to add this xml file?

Comment: i added this `xml` file to my theme path `Magento_Customer\layout`

Comment: <vendor>_<module>::form/edit.phtml replace with Magento_Customer::form/edit.phtml

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: I found out a solution to the problem 
in `register.phtml` file I added `$block->setShowAddressFields(true);` before `if ($block->getShowAddressFields()):` line code
and comment all fields except telephone field that I need to show. but I have got another problem that it doesn't save the phone number

Comment: Telephone field not being saved in the database. I already have an understanding that Telephone is an attribute of customer_address_entity and for me to save the Telephone it needs street, country_id and city.

Now, my question is how do I achieve my goal. Should I set default value for the necessary address fields so that I can save Telephone number during customer registration?

Comment: please attach your code

Comment: I edit my question.
you can see that I added hidden inputs with default values to be able to save telephone in db